Hot reload not working on physical device
Description
When running the project on a physical device, specifically an iPhone 12 with iOS version 17.4.1, the application launches successfully. However, the hot reload feature and development tools deactivate, preventing me from effectively debugging the application.
Expected Behavior:
The application should run on the physical device with active hot reload and development tools, allowing for efficient debugging and development.
Actual Behavior:
Upon running the application on the specified device, the hot reload and development tools are disabled, hindering the debugging process.
It's crucial to say that only happens when the app runs on a physical device, on the simulator works perfectly fine.
Additional Information:

This issue persists consistently across multiple attempts.

No error messages or warnings are displayed during the process.

The problem does not occur when running the application on a simulator


For more information here is the podfile
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'KtdraApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'KtdraAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end

React Native Version
0.72.6
Output of npx-react-native info
System:
  OS: macOS 14.4.1
  CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M2
  Memory: 68.47 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 18.18.2
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.19
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 9.8.1
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2024.04.01.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.15.2
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.4
      - iOS 17.4
      - macOS 14.4
      - tvOS 17.4
      - visionOS 1.1
      - watchOS 10.4
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636
  Xcode:
    version: 15.3/15E204a
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 11.0.22
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.6
    wanted: 0.72.6
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false

Stacktrace or Logs
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace KtdraApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme KtdraApp -destination id=00008101-001608AA0A2B001E")

success Successfully built the app

info Installing and launching your app on iPhone

success Installed the app on the device.

warn No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.

Ive tried:

Modify the xcode scheme

Use another template for the project

Upgrade the react-native version

Use an iPad or another physical device



Having same issue, Did you happen to find a solution?

Yes, fun fact u can just close the app and then reload the js bundler, after that the hotreload works again, strange shit but works.
